# Can I "hook" a subscription in ngrx store

Tags: ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I would like to keep track of how many times a certain key is subscribed to in @ngrx/store. I don't want to have repeated code in each component that subscribes but was hoping to hook into select() somehow. I don't think @effects apply here because I am not looking at dispatched actions.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that subscribing to a key means selecting something from the store.
You can try extending the Store with your own service and using that then override the select method with something like:

```
@Injectable()
class CountingStore<S> extends Store<S> {
    public keyCount: {[key:string]: number} = {};

    public select = (key: string) => {
        keyCount[key] = keyCount[key] ? keyCount[key] + 1 : 1;
        return super.select(key);
    }
}
```